# Still new to python. So confused right now. How do I make this program work?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

So I'm making a little game to teach myself how python works, and it's been okay up to this point, but now I'm completely stuck. I'm sure the logic and formatting of the if and while statement are all wrong, so I'd be happy if people could point me in the right direction - again, REALLY new to programming in general. I'll paste the code, then explain what I'm trying to make it do:

```
import random
import time

print("Welcome to the Dojo!")
print("You have three opponents; they are ready...")
print("Are you?")
print("*To view the rules, type 'rules' ")
print("*To view commands, type 'commands' ")
print("*To begin, type 'start' ")

while True:
    userInput = (input())
    # Rules
    if userInput == "rules":
        print("The rules in this Dojo are simple. Kill your opponent! Fight to the death! Show no mercy!")
        print("Each opponent gets progressively more difficult, whether it be in terms of health or damage.")
        print("To attack, type 'attack'")
        print("May the better (luckier) warrior win")
    # Commands - to be added
    elif userInput == "commands":
        print("Commands will be added soon!")
    # Start
    elif userInput == "start":
            damage = random.randint(1, 50)
            userHealth = int(100)
            opponentHealth = int(100)
            print("Your first opponent is Larry Schmidt. Don't sweat it, he'll be a piece of cake.")
            time.sleep(3)
            print("The battle will begin in")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("5")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("4")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("3")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("2")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("1")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Fight!")
            if userInput == "attack":
                int(userHealth - damage)
                print("You did %(damage) to Larry!")

    # Invalid response
    else:
        print("Enter a valid response, young grasshopper.")
        if userInput == "start" is True:
            continue
```

If you run the program for yourself, everything is okay until you reach the "5, 4, 3, 2, 1, Fight!" part. Then when you type "attack," it gives you "Enter a valid response, young grasshopper." I understand why this is happening, because "attack" doesn't fall under "rules", "commands", or "start". I just don't get how I'm supposed to format it so that after I enter "attack", it actually proceeds and outputs the damage done, etc. I apologize if this is hard to understand, but I think if you run it for yourself, you'll understand what I'm having problems with. Honestly, something tells me I've messed up the if and while statements up entirely, but hey, I'm learning and having fun :P.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This style of coding is affectionately known as "spaghetti code". It's fine for your first project, in that it will hopefully teach you to think about code structure for your next project. If you can split your code into chunks which are independent from each other, it will be easier to see the overall structure of the program. That in turn helps you write bigger, more complicated programs.

Comment: @tripleee: I always thought that "spaghetti code" referred to using `goto`s (which, thankfully, Python doesn't have) to jump around all over the place. This code is not that bad, really. And yes, for later, larger, more complicated programs, functions will be the way to go.

Comment: Python is super cool. Stick with it! I started learning Python/Django  (starting with zero coding knowledge) about 8 months ago and in the last two months I've been able to put together my own web application! Which is fortunate, because we got screwed out of our entire $18,000 seed capital by some crooked 'developers'. Anyway, it's slow and frustrating at first, but well worth it for the freedom and power that the knowledge gives you.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't asking for more input. It's guaranteed that the `userInput` will still be `"start"` at that point.

Your code would benefit greatly from the use of [functions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm). You could really organize the code better that way.

```
def intro():
    print("Welcome to the Dojo!")
    print("You have three opponents; they are ready...")
    print("Are you?")
    print("*To view the rules, type 'rules' ")
    print("*To view commands, type 'commands' ")
    print("*To begin, type 'start' ")

def get_user_input():
    user_input = (input())
    while user_input not in ['rules', 'commands', 'start']:
        print("valid commands are rules, commands and start")
        user_input = (input())
    return user_input


intro()
returned_user_input = get_user_input()
```

There are a lot of ways to do these things, and you'll get better with time. Mainly note that `user_input` only gets updated when you do this:

```
user_input = (input())
```

Which in your code was only done once.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have in the "start" branch of the if conditional will only run once, and `userInput` will still be "start" at that point. The solution, wrap it in a loop. Maybe something like this:

```
elif userInput == "start":
    userHealth = 100
    opponentHealth = 100

    print("Your first opponent is Larry Schmidt. Don't sweat it, he'll be a piece of cake.")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("The battle will begin in")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("5")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("4")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("3")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("2")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("1")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Fight!")

    while opponentHealth > 0 and userHealth > 0:
        userInput = input()

        if userInput == "attack":
            damage = random.randint(1, 50)
            opponentHealth = opponentHealth - damage
            print("You did %d to Larry!" % damage)
```

The while loop will loop until the opponent has been defeated or until the user is defeated, but at the moment, there's no damage done to the user. I'll leave that part to you.

Comment: That looks like fun! Quick let's get this on Steam early access. Also +1 for the `random.randint` function. Maybe I can finally stop using datetime.now() milliseconds for my random integers.

Comment: @AndrewSong: Can you either ask another question or [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33886312/edit) your current one to post the code you have now?

Comment: @El'endia Starman: sorry, I got the "attack"  to work, but when I try to insert a variable into a string I get an error.

Comment: @AndrewSong: Oh, I think I know what you mean. See my edit (I changed the last line), and see also [this webpage](https://pyformat.info/) for more on string formatting.

Comment: @El'endia Starman: Thank you sooooo much. Even if this program is incredibly easy to most people, it's actually immensely thrilling for me, personally, to see things start to come together and work in a program. So satisfying :)